# Is it wise to register all of my custom rules in laravel AppServiceProvider?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering if its wise to register all of my custom rules in AppServiceProvider.php file. Since I could use it everywhere easily with less code by just calling the validation name.

I also tried to do make:rule but I'm not sure which is better.
This is an example of what I registered in my AppServiceProvider:

```
Validator::extend('greater_than_field', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $min_field = $parameters[0];
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $min_value = $data[$min_field];
            return $value > $min_value;
          });   

          Validator::replacer('greater_than_field', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return str_replace(':field', $parameters[0], $message);
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers generally put rules on 'app\Rules' folder. In a big project, there can be many rules. Putting all rules in AppServiceProvider can create chaos and make it harder to debug.

Also, if you use some of your rules in a controller then that controller won't bother about other rules. It will make the operation faster and create less overhead.

So, I think it is wiser to use make:rule approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I guess I'll be doing make:rule approach